# iTunes Connect validation warning - finding problematic code

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

I have been trying to validate and submit an app of mine for sometime but each time the validation process turns up an error saying:

> The app references non-public selectors in Payload/AppName.app/AppName: viewport

I tried using the following command on the binary I create for Ad-Hoc distribution and it turned up two instances of `viewport`:

```
strings - -a -arch all "AppName.app/AppName" | grep viewport
```

But the problem is, I am not able to find the files in which the string occurs. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: are you by any chance integrating the iOS Google+ SDK 1.4.0? i'm getting the exact same validation error, but removing the SDK from my project solved it.

Comment: Yes. I did. I got the "startIndex" warning for version 1.3.0 so I upgraded it only to find this problem. So I have completely removed it for the time being. I will wait until Google fixes this to re-integrate google-ios-api to my project.

Comment: Dropped them a note about this problem on the G+ developers community. https://plus.google.com/108616369849585012362/posts/6A9MR5xrU5n hopefully it gets fixed.

Comment: Great! Hopefully it will. Thanks. :)

Comment: We uploaded with same issues. Apple Rejected it. And after we removing google sdk in my project and resubmitted without any warning. They approved this version. Now we are in situation to use GOOGLE compulsorily..

Comment: You should probably see if they have a new version of their SDK out without the bug. I haven't used it in a while, so I'm not sure. Else, you have to resort to using a previous version that is compatible with your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning was caused by Google+ API 1.4.0 and has been addressed in ver 1.4.1. After the SDK is replaced, the binary passed the validation without any warnings.

Comment: We uploaded with same issues. Apple Rejected it. And after we removing google sdk in my project and resubmitted without any warning. They approved this version. Now we are in situation to use GOOGLE compulsorily.. i'm using Google+ latest SDK and xcode 6